# Found a conflicting setters with name: setWallpaper

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm Trying to remove value from one database and put it in another but the app crashes every time this is executed and i keep getting this error.

code:

```
 firebaseDatabase3= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User Ordered").child(PID);
    firebaseDatabase3.keepSynced(true);

    firebaseDatabase4= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Order Ready").child(PID);
    firebaseDatabase4.keepSynced(true);

    firebaseDatabase5= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User Order Ready").child(PID);
    firebaseDatabase5.keepSynced(true);


 void run1() {

    firebaseDatabase4.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.hasChildren()){

                firebaseDatabase3.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        firebaseDatabase5.child(ID).setValue(firebaseDatabase3);
                        run3();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

            }else{

                firebaseDatabase3.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        firebaseDatabase5.child(ID).setValue(firebaseDatabase3);
                        firebaseDatabase3.removeValue();
                        run3();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


}
```

error

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found a conflicting setters with name: setWallpaper (conflicts with setWallpaper defined on android.content.ContextWrapper)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:521)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.loadOrCreateBeanMapperForClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:329)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:166)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:47)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:675)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:167)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:47)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:675)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:167)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:47)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:675)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:167)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:47)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:675)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:167)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:47)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:675)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:167)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToPlainJavaTypes(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:60)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValueInternal(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:282)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValue(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:159)
        at com.example.shopkeeperapp.UserOrders$7$1.onDataChange(UserOrders.java:241)
        at com.google.firebase.database.Query$1.onDataChange(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:179)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java objects that you want to write to/read from the Firebase database must follow JavaBean conventions for property naming, and can only contain types that can be serialized to/from JSON.

In your case you're trying to write a `android.content.ContextWrapper` object, which does not meet these requirements. This happens from one of these lines:

```
firebaseDatabase5.child(ID).setValue(firebaseDatabase3);
```

The `firebaseDatabase3` in here is a `DatabaseReference`, which does not meet the requirements.

---

It seems like you want to write the value that you read from one location to another location, in which case you need to get that value from the `DataSnapshot` instead of the `DatabaseReference`:

```
firebaseDatabase5.child(ID).setValue(dataSnapshot.getValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your POJO follows the coding STYLE STANDARDS for attributes, methods, and constants; put TRANSIENT on everything inside the POJO that shouldn't be SERIALIZED; the Attributes in Firebase must be EXACTLY the same as in POJO; DO NOT USE, for example: myAtributteURI or executeMyAtributteURI(), but myAtributteUri and executeMyAtributteUri(). Remember that it will run in Debug, but it will bug in the minified, obfuscated version. Therefore, follow the Proguard rules specific to FIREBASE. In this link:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start#proguard